Understanding the completeness axiom
I'm reading through Spivak's Calculus and he introduces the least upper bound property as follows:

If $A$ is a set of real numbers, $A\neq\phi$ and $A$ is bounded above, then $A$ has a least upper bound.

He then goes on to give an example of a set for which the above property does not hold. The set is the following:
$$ A = \{x:x^2 < 2 \land x\in\mathbb{Q}\} $$
This set is bounded above by, for example, $1.5$ and is clearly not empty. However, it does not have a least upper bound.
Spivak dismisses this by saying that the least upper bound property does not apply to rational numbers, but to real numbers.
But isn't set A a set of real numbers? It excludes irrational numbers, yes, but doesn't it consist of real numbers only? Although it includes only rational numbers, isn't it still, technically a "set of real numbers" as required in the least upper bound property? To me, it seems like the hypotheses of the least upper bound property is met by this set and the consequence should apply, but it doesn't.
Another thing I don't understand is that, by Spivak's logic, if the least upper bound property "does not hold for the rational numbers" how does he later assume that it holds for the natural numbers?
In the proof for the theorem that natural numbers are not bounded above, Spivak applies the least upper bound property to naturals by saying that "Suppose $\mathbb{N}$ were bounded above. Since $\mathbb{N} \neq\phi$, there would be a least upper bound $\alpha$ for $\mathbb{N}$.
These are well established concepts so clearly I'm missing something. Could someone explain to me where I'm going wrong?

What Spivak means by "don't apply to rational numbers" is that a bounded set of rational numbers have a least upper bound, but this least upper bound may not be a rational number, so your set $A$ have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}$.

The rationals $\Bbb Q$ are the smallest ordered field. Every other axiom used to define the real numbers is also true for the rational numbers. It is only in the least upper bound (a.k.a., "supremum") property that $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ differ. $A \subseteq \Bbb Q$, but in $\Bbb Q$, it has no supremum. In $\Bbb R$, it does.
